# What does it mean if a girl puts “есть друг” in Семейное положение?

Tags: словоупотребление

I'd like to know what if a girl wrote "есть друг" in her marital status, what does this mean?

Comment: Do ask the girl. Maybe she means you, and that is not a linguistic question.

Comment: It is not a linguistic question.

Comment: that will most likely mean having a boyfriend, but since people can write whatever, you cannot know for sure

Comment: In russian VK(smth like fb) we have only this variant to say "I have a boyfriend"

Comment: @Elena It is a linguistic question - the person asking it does not know the meaning of the word in the particular context. And it does really appear on people's profiles in vkontakte.

Answer (score 2):

That is an odd way to phrase it, but in this context, it probably means she is not single. Barring an odd sense of humor, "друг" most likely means "boyfriend" here.

Answer (score 0):

It means she is in relationship. But that doesn't mean that she is married.